# Python Django "Please correct the errors below." using Django's built-in admin panel

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this error in my form with no context telling me to correct the errors below. I tried doing several things such as adding `blank=True` to every optional field that I could insert it into, logging which I found to be ineffective while using native Django forms, and I even tried commenting out various parts of my `add_fieldset` variable in the `UserAdmin` class.

```py
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    """Define the admin pages for users"""
    order = ['id']
    ordering = ('email',)
    list_display = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email',
                           'password',
                           'first_name',
                           'last_name',
                           'gender',
                           'birthday',
                           'verified_male',
                           'verified_female_1',
                           'verified_female_2'
                )}),
        (
            _('Permissions'),
            {
                'fields': (
                    'is_active',
                    'is_staff',
                    'is_superuser',
                    'verified',
                    'vetted',
                )
            }
        ),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ['last_login']}),
    )
    readonly_fields = ['last_login', 'age']
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': (
                'email',
                'password',
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'gender',
                'birthday',
            )}),
        (
            _('Permissions'),
            {
                'fields': (
                    'is_active',
                    'is_staff',
                    'is_superuser',
                    'verified',
                    'vetted',
                )
            }
        )
    )


admin.site.register(models.User, UserAdmin)
```

Here is my models.py:

```py
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create, save, and return a new user"""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User have must have an email address')

        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email), **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, first_name, last_name, gender, birthday, **extra_fields):
        """Create and return a new superuser"""
        verified = True
        vetted = True
        user = self.create_user(email, password, verified=verified, vetted=vetted, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, gender=gender, birthday=birthday, **extra_fields)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    # verification info
    verified = models.BooleanField()
    vetted = models.BooleanField()
    verified_male = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="male", blank=True)
    verified_female_1 = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="female1", blank=True)
    verified_female_2 = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="female2", blank=True)
    # basic information
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1) # Male = M, Female = F
    birthday = models.DateField()

    @property
    def age(self):
        return (datetime.date.today() - self.birthday).days // 365 # Calculated from birthday

    # profile starts here
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    photos = ArrayField(models.ImageField(upload_to='images'), size=8, null=True, blank=True)
    prompts = ArrayField(models.TextField(), size=4, null=True, blank=True)
    # more info
    height = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True) # height in inches

    objects = UserManager()

    class SeekingChoice(Enum):
        MEN = "Men"
        WOMEN = "Women"
        BOTH = "Both men and women"
    seeking = [(tag, tag.value) for tag in SeekingChoice]

    class EthnicityChoice(Enum):
        WHITE = "White/Caucasian"
        BLACK = "Black/African"
        LATINO = "Hispanic/Latino"
        EAST_ASIAN = "East Asian/Pacific Islander"
        MIDDLE_EAST = "Middle Eastern/Indian"
        OTHER = "Other"
    ethnicity = [(tag, tag.value) for tag in EthnicityChoice]

    class ChildrenStatusChoice(Enum):
        DOESNTHAVE_DOESNTWANT = "Doesn't have/doesn't want"
        DOESNTHAVE_WANTS = "Doesn't have/wants"
        HAS_DOESNTWANTMORE = "Has/doesn't want more"
        HAS_WANTSMORE = "Has/wants more"
    children_status = [(tag, tag.value) for tag in ChildrenStatusChoice]

    class ReligionChoice(Enum):
        PROTESTANT = "Christian/Protestant"
        CATHOLIC = "Christian/Catholic"
        JEWISH = "Jewish"
        MUSLIM = "Muslim"
        BUDDHIST = "Buddhist"
        HINDI = "Hindi"
        AGNOSTIC = "Agnostic"
        ATHEIST = "Atheist"
        OTHER = "Other"
    religion = [(tag, tag.value) for tag in ReligionChoice]

    class PoliticsChoice(Enum):
        MARXIST = "Marxist"
        LIBERAL = "Liberal"
        LIBERTARIAN = "Libertarian"
        CENTRIST = "Centrist"
        CONSERVATIVE = "Conservative"
        APOLITICAL = "Apolitical"
        OTHER = "Other"
    politics = [(tag, tag.value) for tag in PoliticsChoice]

    class PetsChoice(Enum):
        DOG = "Dog"
        CAT = "Cat"
        OTHER = "Other"
    pets = [(tag, tag.value) for tag in PetsChoice]

    class AlcoholChoice(Enum):
        NO = "No"
        SOMETIMES = "Sometimes"
        YES = "Yes"
    alcohol = [(tag, tag.value) for tag in AlcoholChoice]

    class SmokingChoice(Enum):
        NO = "No"
        SOCIALLY = "Socially"
        REGUARLY = "Regularly"
    smoking = [(tag, tag.value) for tag in SmokingChoice]

    class MarijuanaChoice(Enum):
        NO = "No"
        SOCIALLY = "Socially"
        REGULARLY = "Regularly"
    marijuana = [(tag, tag.value) for tag in MarijuanaChoice]

    class EducationLevelChoice(Enum):
        DID_NOT_GRADUATE = "Did not graduate high school"
        DIPLOMA = "Diploma/GED"
        UNDERGRAD = "Undergrad"
        POSTGRAD = "Postgrad"
    education_level = [(tag, tag.value) for tag in EducationLevelChoice]
```